# getting an javascript object attr's

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http-get

Im trying to reach a javascript object, lets say it's called 'john'

```
    // lets say userInput = 'john';
    var userInput = document.getElementById("userInput").value, 

    $http.get(url).then(function (response) {
        var myData = response.data.userInput; // dosent work but response.data.john does
        console.log(myData);
    });
};
```

what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Your server is probably returning it malformed. Its probably returning an object with the key and value. Did you write the server this ajax call is hitting?

Comment: variable myData contains the response from server. In your code snippet, the user input is totally un-related

Comment: @AndrewDonovan the userinput is used in the url for the get function.

Comment: can you update you answer with the server side code giving the response

Comment: @AndrewDonovan im using riots api https://developer.riotgames.com/api/methods#!/1077 - the reponse works fine if i have .john instead of a .userinput (= "john") but the only way i know the username is from the input

Comment: If its an external API you'll have to deal with the format of their response.

Comment: my question being - can i call response.data.(a var string with the name) instead of response.data.(the name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use bracket notation:

```
var myData = response.data[userInput];
```

You are currently asking for the value of the "userInput" property of response.data instead of asking for the property with a name defined by the user's input.

Comment: No worries, I did this once and spent an hour to figure it out. Haven't done it since. You can select my answer as correct if you feel so generous.  ;)

Comment: was waiting for the timer :]

Comment: ohhh so that was what you were trying to do ! lol, didn't know